# Save not working in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a very basic table called radio_inventories

```
 create_table "radio_inventories", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "radio_id"
  t.string   "location"
  t.string   "distributor"
  t.string   "radio_user"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
 end

add_index "radio_inventories", ["radio_id"], name: 
"index_radio_inventories_on_radio_id"
```

Along with a very simple model:

```
class RadioInventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'radio_inventories'
end
```

For some reason when I use the rails console to create new instances of these models and save them, it saves just fine

```
irb(main):001:0> x = RadioInventory.new
=> #<RadioInventory radio_id: nil, location: nil, distributor: nil, radio_user: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> x.radio_id = 123
=> 123
irb(main):003:0> x.save
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "radio_inventories" ("created_at", "radio_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2016-10-18 02:31:26.487353"], ["radio_id", 123], ["updated_at", "2016-10-18 02:31:26.487353"]]
(41.0ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

But when I then try to update the record I get an error.  This happens when I use .save, .update, or .update_attributes.

```
irb(main):004:0> x = RadioInventory.first
RadioInventory Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "radio_inventories".* FROM "radio_inventories"  LIMIT 1
=> #<RadioInventory radio_id: 8565, location: nil, distributor: nil, radio_user: nil, created_at: "2016-10-18 02:22:59", updated_at: "2016-10-18 02:22:59">
irb(main):005:0> x.location = 'IT'
=> "IT"
irb(main):006:0> x.save
  (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
TypeError: nil is not a symbol
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.8/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:162:in `attribute_was'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:44:in `id_was'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:494:in `_update_record'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:70:in `_update_record'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:83:in `_update_record'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310:in `block in _update_record'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310:in `_update_record'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:70:in `_update_record'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:483:in `create_or_update'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in `save'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
... 2 levels...
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
    from (irb):6
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'irb(main):007:0>
```

I've also this with models/tables named "RadioStatus/radio_statuses" which also failed.  But when I try with the model/table named 'RadioTracker/radio_trackers', everything works fine and as expected.
Any insight on why ActiveRecord behaves this way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you did `x(location: "IT")` does that yield the same error?

Comment: Is radio_id your primary key? If it is try adding`self.primary_key = 'radio_id'` to your model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no default primary id for a table, Rails throws this error when we try to update a ActiveRecord object. so you can try putting `self.primary_key = 'radio_id'` at the beginning of `RadioInventory` model class.

And I see that in your migration there is `id: false` so I guess this is the problem.

Comment: This was it, apparently I'm an idiot and forgot...  Thank you

Comment: Everyone does silly mistakes, no body is perfect. No big deal.

Answer (score 0):

You should do assign value on `update_attributes`:

```
x= RadioInventory.first
x.update_attributes(location: 'IT')
```

Comment: I have tried that and it is yielding the same error